# Resolving Java vulnerabilities coming from Pyspark in TwistLock Scan report (Embedded in Jenkins build pipeline)

Tags: java, apache-spark, security, jenkins, pyspark

I have developed a Python - Pyspark data pipeline in my local machine. The version of the spark/pyspark used is the latest 3.4.1. After successfully testing my pipeline in my local I pushed my pipeline to bitbucket repo dev branch.
Now to build an image of the pipelines developed for further deployment to different environments, we have jenkins pipeline created by the DevOps team where there are different stages which are mentioned below :-

Declarative: Checkout SCM
Clone repository
SonarQube Analysis
Build Docker Image
twist lock
Push image
Remove image
Declarative: Post Actions

Every pipeline built is associated with a dockerfile which has the necessary steps required for the python version, pip installation, spark installation and the package installation in requirements.txt.

Now upon building the image for my pipeline, the Cloud Foundry twistlock generates a report of different vulnerabilities regarding OS, Python, Java, CIS and so on. I could resolve all the vulnerabilities however I am not able to figure out how to resolve the java vulnerabilities, given that I am not using java code or any jar file anywhere in my python-pyspark pipeline.

I am attaching the java vulnerabilities scan report for further details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbrMb.png)

I know that pyspark installation has a folder called jars and the vulnerabilities are coming out of the jar versions in that folder; we even tried tried replacing the existing vulnerable jars with the specified jars in the scan report in the dockerfile, but still the same set of java vulnerabilities are coming.

Can you please let me know the steps that needs to be followed to resolve the java vulnerabilities for my python-pyspark pipeline , shown in the picture, coming out of spark 3.4.1? A list of steps will be highly appreciated.